# Doing a decorator Java program. Why does it show a mismatch?

Tags: java, decorator, type-mismatch

I have a question regarding a program I'm doing for school. I have to do the following:

> Write a Java program that uses decorator classes to add capabilities
>   to employees. In a typical company, an employee will be asked to
>   perform a number of duties, such as Department Head, Safety
>   Coordinator, Recruiter, or Community Liason. You should have
>   additional ones besides those. Your Java program will create Employees
>   and then decorate these employees at runtime.
>
> Create an abstract class named Employee, with last name and
>   description fields, and a getDescription() method. Create a concrete
>   class named SalariedEmployee that extends Employee. Create an abstract
>   class named ResponsibilityDecorator that is able to decorate an
>   employee and return the employee's responsibility as a string. It will
>   have an abstract getDescription method. Create some job category
>   classes that extend the ResponsibilityDecorator class and implement
>   the getDescription() method.
>
> In your main test program, create at least 5 Employee objects and pass
>   them to the constructors of each of your decorator classes. The first
>   employee should be you so use your last name. Then, print each
>   Employee by calling its getDescription() method. All employees should
>   not have the same number of responsibilities. The program's output
>   should look something like this for each :
>
> [LastName]: Manager, Recruiter, CommunityLiaison, ProductionDesigner

Here's what I've done so far:

Employee.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Employee 
{
    String lastName, description;

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

}
```

SalariedEmployee.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class SalariedEmployee extends Employee
{
    String lastName, description;

    public abstract String getDescription();
}
```

ResponsibilityDecorator.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class ResponsibilityDecorator
{
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return employee.getDescription();
    }

    Employee employee;

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return employee.equals(obj);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return employee.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return employee.toString();
    }

    public ResponsibilityDecorator(Employee employee) {
        super();
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public ResponsibilityDecorator() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Rodriguez.java (first employee class)

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Rodriguez extends ResponsibilityDecorator 
{
    Employee employee1;

    String lastName = "Rodriguez";
    String description = "Tech Support";

    public Rodriguez (Employee employee1)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Doe.java (second employee class):

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Doe extends ResponsibilityDecorator 
{
    Employee employee2;

    String lastName = "Doe";
    String description = "Security Guard, Police Officer";

    public Doe (Employee employee2)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Jill.java (third employee object):

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Doe extends ResponsibilityDecorator 
{
    Employee employee2;

    String lastName = "Doe";
    String description = "Security Guard, Police Officer";

    public Doe (Employee employee2)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Maria.java (fourth employee class):

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class Maria extends ResponsibilityDecorator
{
    Employee employee4;

    String lastName = "Maria";
    String description = "Receptionist, Valet, Cashier, Restock";

    public Maria (Employee employee4)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

James.java (fifth employee class):

```
import java.util.*;

public abstract class James extends ResponsibilityDecorator
{
    Employee employee5;

    String lastName = "James";
    String description = "Manager, CEO, Economy, President, Analytics";

    public James (Employee employee5)
    {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Test.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Rodriguez();
        System.out.println("Rodriguez:" + 
                employee1.getDescription());

        Employee employee2 = new Doe();
        System.out.println("Doe" + 
                employee2.getDescription());

        Employee employee3 = new Jill();
        System.out.println("Jill:" + 
                employee3.getDescription());

        Employee employee4 = new Maria();
        System.out.println("Maria:" + 
                employee4.getDescription());

        Employee employee5 = new James();
        System.out.println("James:" + 
                employee5.getDescription());
    }
}
```

For some reason, it shows a type mismatch error. I 've been searching around the Internet and I even asked some people. I tried many fixes, but they just create another error. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: "it shows a type mismatch error" Where? What is the error message? (And do you really need to show 5 of the same thing? Would 1 suffice?)

Comment: It's simply that a `ResponsibilityDecorator` isn't an `Employee`.

Comment: This is not good decorator pattern usage. You're using composition where you shouldn't be doing so, and this suggests that you don't yet understand the pattern as yet. Reread your notes or the Wikipedia article on this

Comment: Hello to all who commented on my question. Thank you all for helping me. Along with another fix, I was able to fix the error and finish the program. You guys are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be several problems here. Let's go through the assignment text:

> Create an abstract class named Employee, with last name and description fields, and a getDescription() method.

This looks OK

> Create a concrete class named SalariedEmployee that extends Employee.

You made SalariedEmployee an abstract class. Remove `abstract` and implement the getDescription method.

> Create an abstract class named ResponsibilityDecorator that is able to decorate an employee and return the employee's responsibility as a string. It will have an abstract getDescription method.

According to the decorator pattern I'm familiar with, `ResponsibilityDecorator` should extend Employee if it's supposed to "decorate an employee" - have you been taught something else?

From the description of the task I would expect to see:

```
abstract class ResponsibilityDecorator extends Employee {
    Employee employee;
    ResponsibilityDecorator(Employee e) { this.employee = e; }
    abstract String getDescription();
}
```

> Create some job category classes that extend the ResponsibilityDecorator class and implement the getDescription() method.

You have not done this, unless you consider Maria, Rodriguez etc "job categories."

A "Manager" job category could look like this:

```
class Manager extends ResponsibilityDecorator {
    Manager(Employee employee) { super(employee); }
    String getDescription() { return employee.getDescription() + " Manager"; }
}
```

> In your main test program, create at least 5 Employee objects

Perhaps you confused this step the previous one and created 5 employee classes (Maria, Rodriguez, ...)?

---

Do note that the solution to this exercise would leave professional developers scratching their head, because this is not a reasonable way to represent job categories or responsibilities in a program.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating instances of objects of Type Employee
But none of them have a relationship or are children of the Employee class according to your code.

You defined what a Employee and Salary employee is, but none of your people objects extends them.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic OOP concepts are mismatch in the code.

`abstract class` cannot be used on initialization (as you did)

`Employee employee1 = new Rodriguez();`

 line code is fine, but the error is derived from `Rodriguez class`

Try change class def with:

`public class Rodriguez extends ResponsibilityDecorator`

This will not fix the issue since no relation between `Rodriguez`_`ResponsibilityDecorator`(type) and `Employee`(type) but is a step further in understanding the code.(only have an instance var as `Employee`embedded on `ResponsibilityDecorator`. It could be used to redesign the code and made the link with an `Employee`, but I doubt that you'll follow the pattern.(noted as an alternate solution)

Usually all `employees` should derived from `Employee` then a proper code-adjustment will be `public class Rodriguez extends Employee` ... and after the code should be adapted.(from here you should start).Just look again on pattern.


One more hint, proper `Name_Rodriguez` is not an adequate `class def`, it's more like a property of an instance. Eg:`Employee e1 = new CustomEmployee("Rodriguez","last name", age_int)` and  `CustomEmployee` it's a concrete class which `extends Employee` ... (Employee could be `abstract` or `interface`)